# How to get meaningful backtraces in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have a question and I would be grateful if you could find time to answer.
I have a segmentation fault using Linux + ROS + C, and I want to analyse it.
What I do is the next:

> ulimit -c unlimited

> compiling + running

> gdb my_executable core

> bt

But I receive "??" instead of functions names.

In order to do solve it, I have uncommented the next line in CmakeLiskts.txt file:
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo).

And I also have tried to use: set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

I still have problems...

Your help will be more than appreciated.

Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12156/how-to-get-meaningful-backtraces-in-ros?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your answers, the problem (as always) obvious: wrong executable name.
Still, it is very nice to know, that help can be found here :).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) with karma: 378 on 2011-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1